# Scrolling up a large console.log'ed string in the terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, terminal

Consider I am printing a large string of text in **Node.js**. In this example, consider I am printing the entire bible
ftp://ftp.cs.princeton.edu/pub/cs226/textfiles/bible.txt
(or maybe only one chapter). It's a large block of text, you get the point.

But, when I output the text, in the terminal like this:

```
// str being a large string    
console.log(str)
```

We will be scrolled down in the terminal to the end of the string. And we will have to scroll back up again in the terminal to get to the beginning of the string to look at it.

How can I "scroll back up" to the beginning of the string after its logged (**in code**), so I don't have to manually scroll up. Is this even possible? I was thinking that `man` pages do it, so it could be. Any idea?

Comment: Choose `View -> Scroll To Top` from the menu.

Comment: @codeforester sorry, forgot to mention. I meant using code! haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use blessed.js. Its an ncurses library .
https://github.com/chjj/blessed

Comment: cool answer, can you elaborate a little more? Which type of element would I use?

Comment: A box or a log @candh